# Formatting a cell prevents me from pasting a range

Tags: excel, vba

```
For i = 3 To numPer + 3
    Sheets("Key Assumptions Generated").Select
    Cells(2, i).PasteSpecial

    Cells(1, i).Value = l

    Set curCell = Worksheets("Key Assumptions Generated").Cells(2, i)
    Cells(1, i).NumberFormat = "@"

    l = l + 1

Next i
```

That's my coe. When I remove the 'Cells(1,i).NumberFormat = "@"' code runs fine. But when I try to format the loop will stop running and I'll get an 'Error with the PasteSpecial method of Range class.

Comment: Are you looking to get a fill series of values in the first row starting with `l`? What does `l` start at? I do understand that it is incremented by 1 for each iteration in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you have disovered the act of adjusting a cell's number format will cancel the previous 'dancing ants' copy operation. You cannot paste without something being copied (i.e. residing on the clipboard) first.

Just do everything at once albeit in three steps (it's faster this way in any event).

```
with workSheets("Key Assumptions Generated")
    .Cells(2, 3).resize(1, numper).PasteSpecial
    .Cells(2, 3).resize(1, numper).NumberFormat = "@"
    .Cells(2, 3).offset(-1, 0) = l
    .Cells(2, 3).resize(1, numper).offset(-1, 0).DataSeries Rowcol:=xlRows, Type:=xlLinear, Step :=1
end with
```

Comment: Hi Jeeped,

Thanks for your response. I am sure that you're correct, but I am not too familiar with your code.

Should I paste that in my for loop? What does each line do?